# c structs and byte setting/ ordering

Tags: c

Hi I'm trying to read a byte array into a struct and the bytes are coming out in the reverse order (to how i expected). Can someone help me understand whats happening please?

```
unsigned char buf[] = {
0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44,
0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88,
0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc
};


typedef struct mystruct {
 uint16_t var1;
 uint16_t var2;
 uint32_t var3;
 uint32_t var4;
} something;


int main(int argc,char **argv){

   printf("sizeof buf: %lu %d \n",sizeof(buf),sizeof(something));
   something *st = (something*)&(buf[0]);
   #define pr(a) printf(#a" %x\n",a)
   pr(st->var1);
   pr(st->var2);
   pr(st->var3);
   pr(st->var4);

   return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof buf: 12 12 
st->var1 2211
st->var2 4433
st->var3 88776655
st->var4 ccbbaa99
```

I was expecting something like:
    st->var1 1122

Doing this also seems to output the same thing?

```
memcpy(&st->var1,buf,2);
pr(st->var1);
```

output:
    st->var1 2211

x86/Linux server, gcc version 4.5.3 (if that helps)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might like to read about endianness. You could do this here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for example.

Answer (score 9):

If you read about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), you will see that there are two ways of storing data longer than one byte in memory.

For big-endian systems (like ARM), the integer value `0x1122` is stored in memory as (from lower to higher addresses) `0x11 0x22`. On a little-endian system (like x86) it's stored as `0x22 0x11`.

As your data in the array is stored "big-endian", you get the opposite byte ordering to what you expect on a little-endian system like yours.

Comment: There is also a strict aliasing issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out your main observable issue is that one of [edianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Your method for accessing `buf` is undefined behavior because it violates [strict aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) rules here by type punning here:

```
something *st = (something*)&(buf[0]);
```

If I built this code on using `gcc` using the following arguments:

```
-O3 --Wstrict-aliasing=2
```

I receive the following warning:

```
main.cpp:22:4: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    something *st = (something*)&(buf[0]);
    ^
```

I am currently using version `4.8`. The relevant section from the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) that covers aliasing rules is `6.5/7`.

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim and Shafix have said, you can have problems with padding and endianness, but if you can make use of `#pragma pack` this code should work (swap bytes when little endian)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char buf[] = {
    0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44,
    0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88,
    0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc
};

typedef struct mystruct {
    uint16_t var1;
    uint16_t var2;
    uint32_t var3;
    uint32_t var4;
} something;

static uint16_t swap16(uint16_t val)
{
    return ((val >> 8) & 0xFF) | ((val << 8) & 0xFF00);
}

static uint32_t swap32(uint32_t val)
{
    uint16_t v1 = swap16((uint16_t) val);
    uint16_t v2 = swap16((uint16_t) (val >> 16));
    return (v1 << 16) | (v2);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof buf: %zu %zu \n", sizeof(buf), sizeof(something));
    something *st = (something*)&(buf[0]);

    #define pr(a) printf(#a" %x\n", a)

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN 
    st->var1 = swap16(st->var1);
    st->var2 = swap16(st->var2);
    st->var3 = swap32(st->var3);
    st->var4 = swap32(st->var4);
#endif

    pr(st->var1);
    pr(st->var2);
    pr(st->var3);
    pr(st->var4);

    return(0);
}
```

EDIT:

`#pragma pack` will cause the pre-processor to discard the pre-determined alignment of the structure members and thus no padding bytes would be inserted, you can define your structure as follows:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
typedef struct mystruct {
    uint16_t var1;
    uint16_t var2;
    uint32_t var3;
    uint32_t var4;
} something;
#pragma pack(pop) //back to whatever the previous packing mode was
```

Comment: This version still has the same strict aliasing issue that the original code has.

Comment: You can also just use the POSIX `ntohs` and `ntohl` functions.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, _if you can make use of `#pragma pack`_

Comment: Still violates strict aliasing seeing online example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3356eec1033b8fa39f281c84a1982eca-c0b6239226ddd7a37880fbf82e7636c3

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, obviously you can not compile with `-Wstrict-aliasing=2` :)